# Shellexecute equivalent for Linux as target platform

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Does anyone knows the equivalent for Shellexecute command for Linux as active target platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up wit this:

```
const
   libc = '/usr/lib/libc.dylib';

type
   PIOFile = Pointer;

   // Create a new stream connected to a pipe running the given command.
function popen(const Command: PAnsiChar; Modes: PAnsiChar): PIOFile; cdecl; external libc name 'popen';

// Close a stream opened by popen and return the status of its child.
function pclose(Stream: PIOFile): Integer; cdecl; external libc name 'pclose';

// Return the EOF indicator for STREAM.
function feof(Stream: PIOFile): Integer; cdecl; external libc name 'feof';

// Read chunks of generic data from STREAM.
function fread(Ptr: Pointer; Size: LongWord; N: LongWord; Stream: PIOFile): LongWord; cdecl; external libc name 'fread';

// Wait for a child to die.  When one does, put its status in *STAT_LOC
// and return its process ID.  For errors, return (pid_t) -1.
function wait(__stat_loc: PInteger): Integer; cdecl; external libc name 'wait';


procedure TUtils.RunCommand(const CmdLine: string; results: TStrings);
var
   Output: PIOFile;
   Buffer: PAnsiChar;
   TempString: Ansistring;
   Line: Ansistring;
   BytesRead: Integer;
const
   BufferSize: Integer = 1000;
begin
   TempString := '';
   Output := popen(PAnsiChar(Ansistring(CmdLine)), 'r');
   GetMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
   if Assigned(Output) then
      try
         while feof(Output) = 0 do
         begin
            BytesRead := fread(Buffer, 1, BufferSize, Output);
            SetLength(TempString, Length(TempString) + BytesRead);
            Move(Buffer^, TempString[Length(TempString) - (BytesRead - 1)], BytesRead);

            while Pos(#10, TempString) > 0 do
            begin
               Line := Copy(TempString, 1, Pos(#10, TempString) - 1);
               results.Add(UTF8ToString(Line));

               TempString := Copy(TempString, Pos(#10, TempString) + 1, Length(TempString));
            end;
         end;
      finally
         pclose(Output);
         wait(nil);
       FreeMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
      end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure ShlOpen( FileName: String ) ;   
var prc: TProcess;   
begin   
 prc: = TProcess.Create ( nil ) ;  
 prc.CommandLine: = 'xdg-open' + FileName;  
 prc.Execute;  
 prc.free;  
end ;
```

Comment: I already knew about that class but it's declared in Lazarus, while I was looking that implementation in RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo, where I can't find it on the online help.